# Don't get 1 step of proof eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

I having problem with get a proof of eigenvalues of inverse matrix is $\frac1\lambda$ for orthogonal matrix

$(1)A\mathbf{v} = \lambda\mathbf{v} \implies (2)A^{-1}A\mathbf{v} = \lambda A^{-1}\mathbf{v}\implies (3)A^{-1}\mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{v}$

(1) is just def of eigenvalue i know it

(2) we just multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ right?, A$A^{-1}$ that give us I , so

(3) i think we should get $\mathbf{v} = \lambda A^{-1}\mathbf{v}$ how we move $A^{-1}$ on the left side (i mean what operation we made to do this)

Comment: After step 2 you just divide by $\lambda$ and get step 3 (written in reverse).

Comment: @dxiv thanks mate i could see that but it's obvious when u said that. I think i should go sleep

Comment: What does the orthogonality of the matrix have to do with this? It holds for *any* non-singular square matrix.

Answer (score 2):

They are only dividing (2) by $\lambda$, substituting $A^{-1}A = I$ and inverting the sides of the equality to get (3).